# PHP 2 dimensional array undefined offset error

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to php and I created a web page to take an input username and password, then compare it to a list of stored ones to grant or deny access to the site. My code works properly for what I designed it to do, but I keep getting Undefined offset errors.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Insecure System</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        // read file and set text to string
        $myFile = fopen("includes/users.txt","r");
        $content = fread($myFile,filesize("includes/users.txt"));
        fclose($myFile);

        // set string to two dimensional array
        $contentArray = explode("||>><<||",$content);
        foreach ($contentArray as $cArr) {
            $contentArray2[] = explode(",",$cArr);
        }
        //print_r($contentArray2);

        // retrieve user input values
        if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
            $enteredUser = $_POST['user'];
            $enteredPass = $_POST['pass'];


            // if statements to check user/pass combo
            for ($i=0;$i<=sizeof($contentArray2);$i++) {
                for ($i2=0;$i2<=sizeof($contentArray2[$i]);$i2++) {
                    if ($contentArray2[$i][$i2] == $enteredUser) {
                        $i2++;
                        if ($contentArray2[$i][$i2] == $enteredPass) {
                            echo "Access Granted";
                            break 2;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "Access Denied"; 
                            break 2;
                        }
                    }
                    else continue;
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="user">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="pass">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Contents of the users.txt:

```
beavis,password||>><<||butthead,password2||>><<||dana,alien||>><<||fox,believe
```

Resulting error output: Undefined offset: 2 in index.php on line 29

Line 29 refers to this line in the code:  `if ($contentArray2[$i][$i2] == $enteredUser) {`

Value of $contentArray2: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => beavis [1] => password ) [1] => Array ( [0] => butthead [1] => password2 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => dana [1] => alien ) [3] => Array ( [0] => fox [1] => believe ) )`

Comment: Please print value of $contentArray2

Comment: `$i<=sizeof($contentArray2)` and `$i2<=sizeof($contentArray2[$i])` should be `$i<sizeof($contentArray2)` and `$i2<sizeof($contentArray2[$i])`

Comment: @SterlingH: no worries :)

Comment: Have you told Beavis and Butthead that you store their passwords in plain text in a txt file? All those news stories about password leaks are usually "just" hashes of passwords that is leaked. But you store then as plain text in a txt file accessible by anyone. Think about what you are doing. If you are in Europe, GDPR will cost you lots in fines if this is found out.

Comment: @Andreas, the title of the web page may give this away a bit `<title>Insecure System</title>`

Answer (score 0):

use `<` instead of `<=` in both the `for loops`

```
            // if statements to check user/pass combo
            for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($contentArray2); $i++) {
                for ($i2=0; $i2 < sizeof($contentArray2[$i]); $i2++) {
                    // your other code
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have solved your issue, I wanted to show an alternative method of doing this.

The main idea is to not do so many intermediate steps.  While you are reading the file, why not check the user name and password at this point?

Couple of other things - use `file_get_contents()` as a shorthand for `fopen/fread/fclose` and only read the file if you are going to use it (inside the main `if`)

```
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $enteredUser = $_POST['user'];
    $enteredPass = $_POST['pass'];

    //read file and set text to string
    $content = file_get_contents("a.csv");

    // set string to two dimensional array
    $users = [];
    foreach ( explode("||>><<||",$content) as $user )   {
        list($name, $password) = explode(",", $user, 2);
        // If the user matches
        if ($enteredUser == $name )  {
            // Output depending on password matching
            if ($enteredPass == $password) {
                echo "Access Granted";
            }
            else {
                echo "Access Denied";
            }
            // Exit loop as checked user
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make an associative array with the username, password to make the if granted easy.

```
$myFile = fopen("includes/users.txt","r");
$content = fread($myFile,filesize("includes/users.txt"));
fclose($myFile);

// set string to two dimensional array
$contentArray = explode("||>><<||",$content);
foreach ($contentArray as $cArr) {
     $temp = explode(",",$cArr);
     $contentArray2[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
}
//print_r($contentArray2);

// retrieve user input values
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
     $enteredUser = $_POST['user'];
     $enteredPass = $_POST['pass'];       

     if($contentArray2[$enteredUser] === $enteredPass){ 
         echo "Access Granted";
     }else{
         echo "Access denied";
     }
}
```

or perhaps even simpler. Do a in_array on `username,password`

```
$myFile = fopen("includes/users.txt","r");
$content = fread($myFile,filesize("includes/users.txt"));
fclose($myFile);

// retrieve user input values
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
     $enteredUser = $_POST['user'];
     $enteredPass = $_POST['pass'];       

     if(in_array($enteredUser . "," . $enteredPass, $content)){ 
         echo "Access Granted";
     }else{
         echo "Access denied";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try it

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Insecure System</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            // read file and set text to string
            $myFile = fopen("users.txt","r");
            $content = fread($myFile,filesize("users.txt"));
            fclose($myFile);

            // set string to two dimensional array
            $contentArray = explode(" ",$content);

            foreach ($contentArray as $key => $cArr) {
                $contentArray2[] = explode("||>><<||",$cArr);
            }

            if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
                $enteredUser = $_POST['user'];
                $enteredPass = $_POST['pass'];
                $flag = 0;
                foreach($contentArray2 as $value){
                    if(trim($value[0]) == trim($enteredUser) && trim($value[1]) == trim($enteredPass)){
                        echo "Access Granted";
                        break;
                    }else{
                        $flag = 1;
                    }
                }

                if($flag != 0){
                    echo 'Denied'; die;
                }
            }
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="user">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="pass">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

put this (`shariful||>><<||123456 kabir||>><<||12345678 jack||>><<||987654`) text in users.txt file